# HTML select drop-down with an input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I implement a select-style drop down menu in HTML with an option that is a text input?

The idea being that someone can either select from a list of predefined options, or input their own option.

Comment: `search field  == input text field`

Comment: @MohammadAdil Yeah but you know what I mean :)

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can use input text with "list" attribute, which refers to the datalist of values.

```html
<input type="text" name="city" list="cityname">
    <datalist id="cityname">
      <option value="Boston">
      <option value="Cambridge">
    </datalist>
```

This creates a free text input field that also has a drop-down to select predefined choices. Attribution for example and more information: https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/datalist

Comment: Hi Oleg, the original poster asked for either a plugin or some sample code - could you flesh out your answer to show how to apply the "list" attribute to do what they want? Thank you.

Comment: woah. Now I have just learnt something new. I think not many programmers know this simple trick to solve the problem. Thank you.

Comment: Datalist do the trick, but the display on some browsers (chrome for ex) can become problematic. Contrarily to select element, you cannot style or even simlply have a scrollbar which is a big issue for long lists.

Comment: It's not supported at all in Safari. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Comment: This is a nice plugin that makes data list cross-platform: http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/

Comment: Is there a way to open the select box with only one click. Currently it can be opened if i click twice on the input field or click the down arrow.

Comment: can we have same feature with + (increment)  - (decrement) option selector with open amount also ? not a dropdown

Comment: The problem with this is that the user needs to click the input element twice in order for the list to appear.
It would be incredible if there was an option to have the list appear on the first click or whenever the input element has focus.