# How to get drop down list inside custom input text

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-11">
    <input type="password" class="form-control"  placeholder="Your lastname" id="pwd">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="about-us" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
      </button>
      <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Male</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Female</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get drop down list inside input text field like in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTiyH.png) using bootstrap,but i am not able to get it, though i tried hard, And sorry if seems silly question as i am new to designing ,your help would be much appreciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: you wont get an answer unless posting some code  you've tried

Comment: you can go through this link [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309059/drop-down-menu-text-field-in-one)

Comment: so you need dropdown to select options

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy did so

Comment: @sanojlawrence yes

Comment: @kumarSikandar have you tried this. `is this what you want` https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: read this Bootstrap [Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by this but i think what you're looking for is the following:

```
 <select>
  <option value="value1">value1</option>
  <option value="value2">value2</option>
  <option value="value3">value3</option>
  <option value="value4">value4</option>
</select>
```

Read up on it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp).