# Combining HTML Number & Select Inputs

Tags: html, input

This is what I've tried:

```
<input type="number select" value="12" step="12"></input>
```

I'm trying to acheive:

- an input with up/down arrow that moves between values of 12
- a dropdown on desktop **and a select "spinner" on mobile** (mobile
  safari) with the dropdown values also of 12 (eg., 12, 24, 36, 48,
  ect.)
- an input that can be typed into (typing in any value is fine for now,
  no error notification neccessary if the value is not a value of 12)
- all of this should be one HTML input that can be styled with CSS

Comment: This is not a code writing service. There are samples on the webz.

Comment: I have searched high and low, can you please help me understand how to better phrase the search or the question so I can learn how to do this?

Comment: Also, can you help me understand what I've said that would indicate that I'm looking for someone to write this for me as a service? That is not what I'm looking for. I'd like to understand how this works.

Comment: Can you perhaps point me to one of these such samples?

Comment: When should the dropdown/spinner appear? When the user clicks inside the input?

Comment: @Keara Yes. The dropdown or spinner should appear with multiples of 12 until maybe 5,000 when the user focuses the input.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first bullet point, you can use `min`, `max`, and `step` on the number input to get the up/down arrows to move between multiples of 12, like this:

```html
<input type="number" min="12" max="5000" step="12">
```

To combine a dropdown/spinner and a number input, take a look at this question: [Drop Down Menu/Text Field in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309059/drop-down-menu-text-field-in-one)

The accepted answer should let you do what you need to do, although it takes a bit of coding. Another answer farther down suggests using `<datalist>`, which sort of works and is much simpler but behaves oddly after you enter a value into the input - the dropdown options disappear and you only see the current value as an option. If you're ok with that behavior and just want a simple solution, I recommend using something like below, but if you want something that works a little better, definitely take a look at the question linked above instead.

```html
<input type="number" list="quantities" min="12" step="12">
<datalist id="quantities">
  <option value="12">
  <option value="24">
</datalist>
```

I didn't include all the options up to 5000, but you get the idea. I'm sure there's a way to fill in the options programmatically without typing them by hand, too - I would start by searching for "using an array as datalist options" or something if you're interested in doing that, although I've never done it myself. I imagine there's a way to create an array of options in JavaScript and pass it in.

Comment: EXCELLENT!! This is such a thoughtful answer. I will definitely take a look at that other question and try out a few of these solutions. Thank you @Keara !!!

Comment: Great! I'm so glad it was helpful. If I answered your question fully, please consider accepting the answer as well so that other people with the same question will be able to find it more easily.