# How to search first x digits typing them inside <select> <option>

Tags: html, mysql, html-select

I have this code but imagine it takes 'options' from a database with tousands of lines. How if I want to choose 0010 or 02ff typing it?

```html
    <label for="select">Choose:</label>

    <select id="select">
        <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>    
        <option value="0000">0000</option>  
        <option value="0100">0100</option>
        <option value="0010">0010</option>
        <option value="0001">0001</option>
        <option value="02fe">02fe</option>
        <option value="02ff">02ff</option>
        <option value="03fe">03fe</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: It works just fine for me (except for '00', for some reason)

Comment: Here's something a bit similar... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51335163/combining-html-number-select-inputs