# How to make text input into dropdown button

Tags: wordpress

I've purchased a premium wordpress theme and having hard time changing some elements, for example https://twiga-tours.com/beta/ I want to change "Where to" input text into dropdown but not able to change, Please advice what should i do

Edit: This is the class name I'm getting when I inspecting the elements

[Where to Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2MqD.png)

But when I search through theme files this class doesn't exist that's why i'm asking where to put code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="India">
    <option value="mum">Mumbai</option>
    <option value="del">New Delhi</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Africa">
    <option value="ken">Kenya</option>
    <option value="eth">Ethoipia</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

For better understanding
[Drop Down Menu/Text Field in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309059/drop-down-menu-text-field-in-one)

Comment: This is just a sample code you need to modify it according to your purpose and put it in the place where you want it to be i.e. replace <input type="text"....> to <select> ... </select>

Comment: Sir Can you please again see the job post, I've updated

Comment: I'm not able to find this code in my theme files, therefore I'm asking you where to change the code.

Comment: The inspect image you posted has the input tag with type text means it will take input, you just have to check the same and remove the whole input part and replace it with select tag or you can just add selectboxoptions and enter all the values in it.