# Dropdown Menu - How to let the user make additions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown

I currently have a form with some fields and a simple dropdown where you can choose an options from a list of options.

Here's the code of the dropdown:

```
<select name="typeOfTokens" required="required">
    <option value="1">Samsung</option>
    <option value="2">Sony</option>
    <option value="3">Android</option>
</select>
```

What I would like to achieve is to let the user search through that list from a text input, I have seen a couple of times a dropdown with a text input at the top. And if there where no matches, then let the user choose whatever he typed, and then take the selected value from the options or whatever is on the text input when submitting the form.

I've seen a couple of dropdown plugins, like "chosen" or "select2" but I didn't find anything really usefull, unless I missed something from the docs.

If anyone could help me out I'll be very gratefull!

Comment: So you want a search engine so-to speak?

Comment: You can show a positioned textfield over the first option if it was selected, hide it when some other option is selected. Positioning in different browsers is challenging though.

Comment: why not jqueryui autocomplete https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Is something like this,similar to what you need ? http://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/vc7yc2a7/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML combo box with option to type an entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14614702/html-combo-box-with-option-to-type-an-entry)

Comment: @MuntasirAlam Yes, just like that, but only allow one selection.

Comment: What do you mean only allow one selection? I'm a bit confused on the question sorry. After I know what you mean I can post the code below.

Comment: nice solution in this 'off-topic' marked topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992085/html-select-drop-down-plugin-with-an-open-text-input-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the combo box provided by Kendo UI. It lets you to select items from the list or to type a new item. I have created a sample demo here - [Combobox Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iNEVI)

If you are new to Kendo, it's has got a core version which is free and has support for lot of widgets including ComboBox

[Kendo UI Core](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/open-source-core)

[Getting started with Kendo ComboBox](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/combobox/overview)