# How to clear datalist input when options are opened?

Tags: html, html-datalist

I have a html5 input with associated datalist, I want to clear the input when the options are opened so that all of them could be visible (unfiltered). How could I do this in Javascript? (with jQuery or not)

For example (https://stackoverflow.com/a/29755076/2190425)

```
<input type="text" name="city" list="cityname">
<datalist id="cityname">
  <option value="Boston">
  <option value="Cambridge">
</datalist>
```

When I click the dropdown arrow, then select Boston and after that click the dropdown arrow again - after this second click I want the input to be empty (because it filters the options to the one option that's typed in - Boston), so I need some kind of event or something that would allow me to empty the input, but it can't be `input` event, because nothing is input when you click the dropdown yet.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with example. Not able to understand what you want to accomplish

Comment: Do you want an editable dropdown?

Comment: Thanks, I added an explanation!

Comment: Let me know if it worked

Comment: Hello @Aurimas , I have the same problem. How did you solve it?

Comment: @alebupal see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did was simply clean the input on double click. This way at least the user has the option and if informed - the usage is quite comfortable (for new users it could less of a solution).

Here is the code I used:

```
# datalist does not fire change event, therefore we need this exception, the if is for avoiding duplicate call with keyup
$(@dom.search_fields).find('input.datalist_filter').on 'input', (e) =>
  @handleInput(e) if e.target.value.length and
                    ($(e.target.list).find('option').filter -> this.value == e.target.value).length

# it does not fire event if you set the value of input manually, therefore we need to call handleInput directly here
$(@dom.search_fields).find('input.datalist_filter').on 'dblclick', (e) =>
  e.target.value = ''
  @handleInput(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go with editable dropdown which will work as datalist and your requirement will be accomplished. The code for editable drop down given below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
    $(".editableBox").change(function(){         
        $(".timeTextBox").val($(".editableBox option:selected").html());
    });
});
```

```css
.editableBox {
    width: 75px;
    height: 30px;
}

.timeTextBox {
    width: 54px;
    margin-left: -78px;
    height: 25px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <select class="editableBox">        
        <option value="1">01:00</option>
        <option value="2">02:00</option>
        <option value="3">03:00</option>
        <option value="4">04:00</option>
        <option value="5">05:00</option>
        <option value="6">06:00</option>
        <option value="7">07:00</option>
        <option value="8">08:00</option>
        <option value="9">09:00</option>
        <option value="10">10:00</option>
        <option value="11">11:00</option>
        <option value="12">12:00</option>
        <option value="13">13:00</option>
        <option value="14">14:00</option>
        <option value="15">15:00</option>
        <option value="16">16:00</option>
        <option value="17">17:00</option>
        <option value="18">18:00</option>
        <option value="19">19:00</option>
        <option value="20">20:00</option>
        <option value="21">21:00</option>
        <option value="22">22:00</option>
        <option value="23">23:00</option>
        <option value="24">24:00</option>
    </select>
    <input class="timeTextBox" name="timebox" maxlength="5"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks good, but I specifically want to work with the native html5 control, since it looks really nice in my application (displaying number values and names in the dropdown).

Comment: Are you going to use it or You are checking into datalist part.

Comment: I am using it! .. it's just that I'm developing for a private company so I don't want to post code examples from it.

Comment: No, I mean I'm  using datalist, but I'm not using your answer, it's not a good fit for me. I voted it up though!

Comment: ok no problem . Can you provide solution you are using It will me help me as well