# How to get unfiltered datalist, when i select input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-datalist

I've got input, that shows some values when i type number. That i wanna do is show all `datalist`, when i try try select. I found [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46084537/9118267), but it is written in jquery.

How to show all option no matter what i'm input?

```
<span>
    <input
      type="number"
      list="values"
      value={this.state.values}
      onChange={this.valuesHandler}
    />
    <datalist id="values">
      <option value="200" />
      <option value="250" />
      <option value="300" />
      <option value="350" />
      <option value="500" />
    </datalist>
  </span>
```

onChange

```
  valuesHandler(e) {
    this.setState({ values: +e.target.value })
    this.forceUpdateHandler()
  }
```

Now it looks like that

[image]

But it should look like that on any value

[image]

Comment: You question is not very clear. Can you include some example e.g. when you input something, what should be expected ?

Comment: Added some examples

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately (as of today) it is not possible to control the display of `datalist options` with css.

`datalist` was created to filter on the input as you type.

I would recommend creating your own autocomplete or dropdown component using different elements if you need something more flexible.

Something like react-select https://jedwatson.github.io/react-select/ might work as well.

More info on datalist here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp