# Dropdown list with others option which allows us to add value manually

Tags: html, css, dom

I need a Dropdown list with others option which allows us to add value manually if the user's field is not in a dropdown list. is it possible?

Thanks in advance,
Balaji

Comment: So something like an input box will come if I choose the others option? Is that what you are looking for. ?

Comment: Exactly @AbinThaha

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18309059/drop-down-menu-text-field-in-one  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992085/html-select-drop-down-with-an-input-field https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5650457/html-select-form-with-option-to-enter-custom-value Duplicate IMO.

Comment: But is its possible that we can type in other option

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is a duplicated question, let me give you a direct method using plain JavaScript and HTML. Check and let me know

```js
function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
      var input = document.getElementById("others-text");
      if (x === "others") {
        input.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        input.style.display = "none";
      }
    }
```

```html
<div>
      <select name="select" id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="others">Others</option>
      </select>
      <input
        style="display: none"
        type="text"
        name=""
        id="others-text"
        placeholder="User Input"
      />
    </div>
```